# I am trying to identify and treat white fungus at the base of a tree

Tags: trees, tree-care, fungus

There is some sort of fungus growing at the base of tree in front of my house. I believe the tree is a Callery Pear Tree. The location is on the sidewalk in Brooklyn, NY. I would like to know if this is something I should worry about and treat? How do I treat this? I tried looking at images of other tree diseases online, but couldn't find anything that looks similar. Thanks in advance for your time.

[image: picture of fungus around base of tree]

[image: close-up of fungus]

Comment: What kind of tree? Your profile says you're in New York City; is this tree there too (knowing your location can narrow down the possibilities)?

Comment: Yes. I'm in NYC. Brooklyn to be exact. I'm embarrassed to say I don't know why type of tree. I'll identify it when I get home tonight and update this question. I _think_ it _might_ be a callery pear tree?

Comment: Is this fungus growing on woody roots of the tree, or just on the ground at the base? Is the tree completely healthy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had another look and the fungal growth does appear to be on the trunk and base of the tree. I think you need to call an arborist to check the tree - it looks as though it may be unsafe either now or eventually, since the fungal attack is near the base, and there may be more fungal activity within the woody roots as well as inside the trunk which is not visible. If there is such infiltration, this will compromise the tree's ability to remain upright and may represent a danger to persons or property nearby.

Comment: I opened a ticket with 311 (NYC's non-emergency number) and they are sending the parks department to look at it. I'd hate for the tree's condition to the point where it's a danger to anyone. Right now the rest of the tree looks  healthy, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Hopefully its just caused by wet weather and excessive dampness on the outside, and doesn't indicate a deeper problem...